# PyQt app with API server. Unable to QTextEdit.setText()

Tags: python, pyqt, fastapi, pyqt6, uvicorn

I am trying to run PyQt (PyQt6.4.0) server with fastapi (0.89.1) and uvicorn (0.20.0). The code is as following:

```
# PyQt with server code
from fastapi import FastAPI
import threading
import uvicorn
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QTextEdit)
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import (QRect)


# main window app in main thread
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
        self._initial_widgets()
        self._create_server()

    def _initial_widgets(self):
        self.textedit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textedit.setGeometry(QRect(100, 0, 100, 100))
        self.textedit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)

    def _create_server(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()

        @self.app.post("/")
        async def change_textEdit_data():
            self.textedit.setText("hello") # By removing this important line there is no issue
            return {"detail": "OK"}

        # The server is going to be run in a child thread
        # I believe that this is the source of the issue
        # Child thread does not have access to self in parent thread
        thread = threading.Thread(target=uvicorn.run, kwargs={"app": self.app, "port": 80}) 
        thread.start() # runs server in separate thread


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

And to send a request to it

```
# Code to send test signal
from time import sleep
import requests as req


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sleep(1)
    r = req.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:80")
    print(r.text, r.status_code)
```

Running order

1. PyQt with server code
2. Code to send test signal

The server has to be run in a thread to avoid UI freezing. (The freezing is not the actual issue)

The issue is that after I start the 2nd code in another process the following is appearing in console of the first one:

```
INFO:     Started server process [14400]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

It crashes.

Just by removing line self.textedit.setText("hello"), the issue is fixed, but the line is important.

Could someone suggest on what should I use to be able to change text in the textbox by using data received from API in PyQt app.

It is important that I keep PyQt and for the other libraries some other options can be suggested, i.e. sth instead of uvicorn.

Edit:

After I remove `self.textedit.setText("hello")` I am getting an expected reply

```
{"detail":"OK"} 200
```

So, the issue is definitely something with that line.

Comment: I've never had the opportunity to work with async, and I'm not familiar with uvicorn, but whenever I see the keywords "UI" and "threading", the answer is almost always the same: UI elements are **not** thread safe, and must not be accessed from external threads. Create a QThread subclass with a custom signal, and emit that signal from the async function; then connect that signal to the function that actually sets the text.

Comment: @musicamante your suggestion was correct. Thank you very much for the advice! By the way would you like to post the suggestion above as an answer and I will provide the solution code in the end of my question as a new edit.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @musicamante, the solution is simple:

1. Create a signal and create an instance of that object as below:

```
class Signals(QObject):
    text_signal = pyqtSignal(str)


signals = Signals()
```

2. Create a function in the `MainWindow` class to change the text as follows:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    ...

    def set_textEdit(self, data):
        self.textedit.setText(data)
```

3. Connect the signal and the function:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        ...

        signals.text_signal.connect(self.set_textEdit)
```

4. Create implementation of `emit` in the API

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    ...

    def _create_server(self):

        ...

        @self.app.post("/")
        async def change_textEdit_data(data):
            signals.text_signal.emit(data) 
            return {"detail": "OK"}
        
        ...
```

Everything else remains the same and the final code is

```
# PyQt with server code
from fastapi import FastAPI
import threading
import uvicorn
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QTextEdit)
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import (QRect, pyqtSignal, QObject)


class Signals(QObject):
    text_signal = pyqtSignal(str)


signals = Signals()


# main window app in main thread
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
        self._initial_widgets()
        self._create_server()
        signals.text_signal.connect(self.set_textEdit)

    def _initial_widgets(self):
        self.textedit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textedit.setGeometry(QRect(100, 0, 100, 100))
        self.textedit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)

    def _create_server(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()

        @self.app.post("/")
        async def change_textEdit_data(data):
            signals.text_signal.emit(data)
            return {"detail": "OK"}

        thread = threading.Thread(target=uvicorn.run, kwargs={"app": self.app, "port": 81})
        thread.start()

    def set_textEdit(self, data):
        self.textedit.setText(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```